# how to rowCount for two values in one query using pdo?

Tags: php, validation, pdo

I am trying to create a signup page and need to validate if username and email already exit.

If I do it in two queries, it works fine, but switch to one query, then it doesn't work properly, it doesn't validate one of value sometimes.

I tried as following but its not working properly, sometimes it doesn't validate for email or username:

```
  $uname = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

    $sql = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";
    $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt1->bindParam(":username", $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->execute();
    if($stmt1->rowCount() == 1){
    $rows = $stmt1->fetch();

      if($rows['username'] == 1){
        $errors['username'] = "Username already in use.";
      }else{
        $username = $uname;
      }
      if($rows['email'] == 1){
        $errors['email'] = "Email already in use.";
      }else{
        $email= $email;
      }
    }
    unset($stmt1);
```

Comment: I would just change it to test `$stmt1->rowCount() > 0` and just say 'Some details are already used'.  Otherwise you may be giving people hints about possible users details if they are trying to hack your website.

Comment: So do I have to change WHERE claus to `WHERE username = :username AND email = :email";` then ? OR to AND ?

Comment: Leave it as OR.

Comment: rowCount is useless in your code. You don't need it at all. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rowCount` method returns >= 1 records when username or email match. Try that code:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$errors = array();

$sql = "SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt1->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->execute();

if($stmt1->rowCount() > 0){
    $rows = $stmt1->fetchAll();

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if($row['username'] === $username) {
            $errors['username'] = "Username already in use.";
        }

        if($row['email'] === $email) {
            $errors['email'] = "Email already in use.";
        }
    }
    $stmt1->closeCursor();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vircom looks like it works fine. litle Question what is different between `$stmt1->closeCursor();` and `unset();` ?

Comment: It's explained in documentation:
 `PDOStatement::closeCursor() frees up the connection to the server so that other SQL statements may be issued, but leaves the statement in a state that enables it to be executed again.`

`unset` just remove variable from memory.

Comment: You don't need rowCount. You should not use it.

Comment: And what's the point in having either closeCursor() or unset()?

Comment: Also, rowCount is useless in your code. You don't need it at all. Just remove it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on that @Dharman I already removed rowCount in VirCom 's answer. using it like so : `$sql = "SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt1->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->execute();

    $rows = $stmt1->fetchAll();`  But I dont think it will change anything if use or not. will it ?

Comment: what I have learned is always close statements when query is executed, as specialy you guys told that many times :) @YourCommonSense

Comment: rowCount is unreliable. Don't use it, because there's never any need for it.

Comment: @Dharman yes, it was very convenient: ) I was about to leave it under the answer when spotted it under the question

Answer (score 0):

You Just get count from this query

```
$sql = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";
```

instead of

```
$sql = "SELECT uid,count(uid) FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";
```

Hope it will help with single query

Comment: Y our solution is works almost same as mine too, it allows to singup with same email or username sometimes when refreshing browser with exist values. might be because of my validating will check it.

Comment: May I ask a question on your answer please ? lets say I am doing a multiple query with `left join` or `inner join` and need to count each table rows and show them on page like : table 1 has 5 items and table 2 has 10 items, how could I do that ? I know its another question but your answer is very close to that question :) @Gowtham coder

Comment: I don't think both tables having different row counts (Using left join or inner join) If i m wrong correct me

Comment: Or Another way use sub query ..SELECT 
    vehicles.title,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE vehicles.id = comments.vehicle_id) AS comments_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images WHERE vehicles.id = images.vehicle_id) AS images_count
FROM vehicles .. Its just a example Hope it will clarify

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Actualy I know sub queries, I am stack on easy part I think :) is it possible to show result of your query like: (Total 10 comments) and (Total 10 images) if its then how ? this where I am stack on dont know how to show total result  :)  I do it with separate queries for each table.